# Selective Line Printing Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Please I'm trying to print the first 7 and the last 7 lines of a file in Ubuntu. I used the command **$ sed '='**  to find number the lines in the files and then I used **$ sed '8,456d'**  to delete those lines (file has 463 lines). It worked but I'm looking for a one-line solution without necessarily having to find out the exact number of lines the file has.

Comment: Why don't you use both `head` and `tail` command in combination to print the first and last 7 lines?

Comment: Can you show me how to combine them in a one-liner?

Comment: Sure, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple one-liner would be,

`head -n7 /path/to/file.txt && tail -7 /path/to/file.txt`

Comment: Thanks. Worked smoothly. Guess I have to practise more.